# Object required error when setting range from two cells

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to convert a text file to Excel sheet. I have to remove some data elements and copy some data elements to several columns. To remove some data, I have to look for a certain String (RUN). After I have that address, I have to search for the next RUN. Inside those two String range, I have to search for another String (NET) and remove it. I have to do it throughout the datasheet since this is frequent.

Here is the code I am trying to use.

```
Dim name As String: name = "RUN"
Dim secondName As String: secondName = "NET"

Dim rgSearch As Range
' set the range to entire sheet
Set rgSearch = Range(Cells.Address)

Dim rgSearch1 As Range


Dim cell As Range
'search for first occurrence of RUN
Set cell = rgSearch.Find(name)
Dim tempCell As Range


' If not found then exit
If cell Is Nothing Then
    Debug.Print "Not found"
    Exit Sub
End If

' Store first cell address
Dim firstCellAddress As String, firstRow As Integer, secondRow As Integer
'store address of first result
firstCellAddress = cell.Address
secondRow = cell.Row


Do
    'save range to another range for next iteration
    Set tempCell = cell.Select
    'row variables are for alternate solution I tried
    firstRow = secondRow
    Debug.Print "Found: " & cell.Address
    ' search for next instance
    Set cell = rgSearch.FindNext(cell)
    ,set next instance
    secondRow = cell.Row

    Set rgSearch1 = Range(tempCell, cell).Select


Loop While firstCellAddress <> cell.Address
```

I have also tried using

```
Set rgSearch1 = Range("B" & firstRow + 1 & ":B" & secondRow - 1).Select
```

instead of putting cells inside the range but I get the same result. That is why those firstRow, secondRow variables are there.

With both ideas, I am getting Object Required error. Could someone please show me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Not sure what you're doing, but it should be `Set tempCell = cell` without the Select.

Comment: I tried. Still the same error. I will add more comments to the code to make it clearer.

Comment: On the same line? You need to get rid of all the Selects.

Comment: Ohhh I forgot to remove select from the bottom statement. This worked.

Removing select from 

Set tempCell = cell.Select 
and
Set rgSearch1 = Range(tempCell, cell).Select

solved it.